# How to return custom response in django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to know how can we return error/success custom response in Django rest instead of serializer response. For example
I want to return the response in the following format

```
{
  'status':'Error',
  'reson':'Reason'
}
```

whereas serializer return errors as in the following format

```
 {'username': ['This field is required.'], 
     'password': ['This field must be at least 8 chars'],
     'email': ['This field cannot be blank']
    }
```

How to customize this error response? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is updating serializer.data dictionary from your view.

```py
serializer.data['status'] = 'Error'
serializer.data['reason'] = 'Reason'

return Response(serializer.data)
```

There are better solutions such as creating custom decorators or creating custom Response object which inherited from Response class. It`s up to you.

Answer (score 1):

def func(request):

```
try:   
        return Response(serializer.data)

    else:
        Response({'detail': 'Write your custom message here'},
                 status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
except:
    return Response({'detail': 'Write your custom message here'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```